# Passing a parameter to a const

Tags: typescript

Being fairly new to typescript, i have a quick question that i can't seem to figure out.

I am trying to use two parameters that i pass to my function to help me obtain values from a object

```
export type Ontology = 'Ren' | 'Covea'
export type Client = 'GMF' | 'default'
export type TabEnum =  Array<LabelledEnum<string>>
export type MapTabRestClientEnum = Record<Client, TabEnum>
export type MapTabRestOntEnum = Record<Ontology, MapTabRestClientEnum>

export function getTabEnumByMandant<K extends Ontology, T extends Client> 
(ontology : K, client: T) {
    return TypeRendezVousValuesMap[ontology].[client]
}

export const TypeRendezVousValuesCovea = (<T extends MapTabRestClientEnum>( 
o: T) => o)({
    GMF : fromNameLabels([
        ["RdvGalant","Rendez vous galant"],
        ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
    ]),
    default : fromNameLabels([
        ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
    ]) 
}) 

export const TypeRendezVousValuesRen= (<T extends MapTabRestClientEnum>(o: 
T) => o)({
    GMF : fromNameLabels([
        ["Site","Sur site"],
        ["Visio","En visio"],
        ["Telephonique","Par téléphone"],
        ["RdvGalant","Rendez vous galant"],
        ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
        ["MatchSquash","match de squash"],
    ]),
    default : fromNameLabels([
        ["Telephonique","Par téléphone"],
        ["RdvGalant","Rendez vous galant"],
        ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
        ["MatchSquash","match de squash"],
    ]) 
})

export function fromNameLabels<T extends string>(src: Array<[T, string]>): 
Array<LabelledEnum<T>> {
    return src.map(([name, label]) => ({ name, label }))
}

export function fromLabelledEnum<T extends string>(src: 
Array<LabelledEnum<T>>): { [K in T]: K } {
    return src.reduce((res, {name, label}) => {
        res[name] = name
        return res
    }, Object.create(null))
}


export const TypeRendezVousValuesMap= (<T extends MapTabRestOntEnum>(o: T) 
=> o) ({
    'Ren': TypeRendezVousValuesRen,
    'Covea': TypeRendezVousValuesCovea
})
```

getTabEnumByMandant('Covea', 'GMF' )

What i want to do is something like this but instead of Ren and GMF putting the parameters instead

```
export function getTabEnumByMandant<K extends Ontology, T extends Client> 
(ontology : K, client: T) {
    return TypeRendezVousValuesMap.Ren.GMF
}
```

Instead of giving me the right answer when i use the paramters, it always gives me this answer:

```
const TypeRendezVous2: {
    Site: "Site";
    Visio: "Visio";
    Telephonique: "Telephonique";
    RdvGalant: "RdvGalant";
    RdvSport: "RdvSport";
    MatchSquash: "MatchSquash";
}
```

Comment: I suggest trying to turn the code above into a genuine [mcve] if you want timely and targeted answers.  As it stands there's a lot to wade through (you can probably trim down a bunch of that code) and is not complete (`LabelledEnum` is not defined anywhere).  Ideally the code would be something you could drop into [a standalone TS compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and run to immediately see the issue.   Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Sorry rather new to stack overflow. Will try to better next time. Anyway found my problem, very silly mistake, just not using the right syntax. I wasn't using [ " something "] to pass my parameter.

Comment: nice that you added the solution...